# Secure connection between two clients with shared secret

Tags: encryption

I am creating a system where there are multiple clients, each of which has a secure connection to a central server which could pass out shared secrets to each of them.

I could be wrong, but I am under the impression that communicating securely if you have a shared secret is a solved problem.  Are there any standard ways of doing this?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a secured TCP connection.

Comment: If it's a password, TLS-SRP is your protocol of choice - if available. If it's a high-entropy shared secret, TLS-PSK with AES-GCM is your ciphersuite (TLS v1.2)

Comment: There are a couple of ways "shared secret" can be interpreted.  Do you mean shared secret as in a Diffie Hellman shared secret, or as a Pre Shared Key (often a passphrase)?

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases you may want to consider:

1. You want to use TCP as the underlying transport protocol and can afford public-key cryptography.
2. You want to use TCP as the underlying transport protocol but can't afford public-key cryptography (because it would be too slow, applies mainly to IoT devices)
3. You want to use TCP, but you want security at a lower level.

Now the first two scenarios have the same answer: You want to use [*Transport Layer Security*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (TLS) v1.2 or newer (as soon as v1.3 gets standardized).
TLS offers multiple *ciphersuites*, which define which methods to use for key-exchange, for authentication, for buld-encryption and for shared-secret-derivation.
The general setting you want to use is [TLS-PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK) in the first two scenarios.
The ciphersuite of choice is `TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` as long as there is no `TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` (which may be standardized *soon*). This will only use pre-shared keys for authentication and ECDH for key-agreement, giving you different keys for each connection (which is good).
In the second scenario the ciphersuite of choice is `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, giving you a modern ciphersuite. The drawback is that the keys aren't negotiated separately, meaning if you once lose the master-secret all connections (future and past) will be compromised, which wouldn't be the case with scenario 1.

The last scenario is a bit more complicated and I'd strongly suggest you to stick with TLS.
 However if can't use TLS (which is widely available), you have to use [IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec), which offers PSK authentication as well. This will secure the connection at the IP level.